# How to get and use associative array from YAML to action in Symfony?

Tags: arrays, symfony1, yaml, associative

Ive got in app.yml some configration data, and I want to foreach them in action. I try do this by get them by sfConfig::get('app_datas') but it fails. Lets show them in details:

YAML:

```
all:
  datas:
    foo: bar
    foo2: bar2
```

and in the actions.class.php I try use this code:

```
foreach (sfConfig::get('app_datas') as $key => $value) {

    echo "key $key has value $value";

}
```

it doesnt work because sfConfig::get('app_datas') is NULL, how simly get it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When Symfony loads `app.yml` config files, it only stores the 2nd level down. So you can't access `app_datas` directly. If you want to get an array containing `foo` and `foo2`, make a YAML file like:

```
all:
  datas:
    baz:
      foo: bar
      foo2: bar2
```

You can then do `sfConfig::get('app_datas_baz')` which will be an array containing `foo` and `foo2` as keys.

**On Edit**: kuba's way is better than a dummy; forgot you could do that.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to access first level as an array you can introduce dummy level in between, just like @jeremy suggested. **Prefix it with a dot** if you don't want it to actually appear in config the variable names:

```
all:
  .baz:
    datas:
      foo: bar
      foo2: bar2
```

Now you should be able to access your data with:

```
foreach (sfConfig::get('app_datas') as $key => $value) 
{
  echo "key $key has value $value";
}
```

Comment: way to go, kuba - saved my day on a hard deadline!

Comment: Minor correction: the dotted value on the second line (.baz) should have a colon suffix, same as the other lines. (I'll make an edit).